# Pl/SQL declaration of table variables and setting options

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to create an anonymous block where I do the following:

```
set session set current_schema = PTSI;
DECLARE
var_cur_proj structure.structure_code%TYPE;
var_cur_task structure.structure_code%TYPE;
TYPE tbl_result AS OBJECT
(
  projeto_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
  projeto structure.description%TYPE,
  tarefa_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
  tarefa structure.description%TYPE,
  recurso_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
  recurso structure.description%TYPE,
  perfil_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
  perfil structure.description%TYPE,
  rate_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
  rate_value rate_change_point_res.rate_value%TYPE,
  dia date,
  horas_reportadas NUMBER(38,2),
  horas_integradas_realizadas NUMBER(38,2),
  horas_integradas_remanescentes NUMBER(38,2),
  horas_planeadas NUMBER(38,2)
);
TYPE table_resul IS TABLE OF tbl_resul;
resultado table_result;
BEGIN

END;
/
```

This is giving me an error... I'm following this site for creating the table variable (http://ss64.com/oraplsql/declaretbl.html) seeing that it did not worked, I tried to create the table variable like I'm used to create tables to be returned by functions (create the object then the table).

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: In general, you cannot have an anonymous block that only declares local variables but does not do anything.  You'd need to at least have a `NULL;` between your `BEGIN` and `END`.  Of course, that would mean that your anonymous block doesn't do anything since you'd be creating local variables whose scope is the anonymous block so they would get deallocated without ever being used...

Answer (score 3):

Rather than creating as object you should create this as a record then declare the table from the record, and as mentioned by Justin above you must have at least a `null;` between the Begin and End tags. Please see amended code below. And http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/record_definition.htm for more details.

```
alter session set current_schema = PTSI;

DECLARE
  var_cur_proj structure.structure_code%TYPE;
  var_cur_task structure.structure_code%TYPE;
  TYPE rec_result IS RECORD
  (
    projeto_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
    projeto structure.description%TYPE,
    tarefa_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
    tarefa structure.description%TYPE,
    recurso_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
    recurso structure.description%TYPE,
    perfil_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
    perfil structure.description%TYPE,
    rate_id structure.structure_code%TYPE,
    rate_value rate_change_point_res.rate_value%TYPE,
    dia date,
    horas_reportadas NUMBER(38,2),
    horas_integradas_realizadas NUMBER(38,2),
    horas_integradas_remanescentes NUMBER(38,2),
    horas_planeadas NUMBER(38,2)
  );
  TYPE table_result IS TABLE OF rec_result;
  resultado table_result;
BEGIN
  null;
END;
/
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, This seems to work, but i'm unable to select from resultado. Maybe i'm using the worng approach here... 
    SELECT * from resulatdo; -- table does not exist
    SELECT * from table(resultado); --types not allowed in sql statements

Comment: Hi, although the type is called 'Table' they are actually just advanced arrays, so you can not use SQL to select from them. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch4.htm) for more details...

Comment: If you want to be able to select from them via sql I would suggest you need to look into a global temporary table.  Link to the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400) look for the heading 'Creating a Temporary Table'.  This gets created once not as part of the anonymous block, but each session / transaction will only see the records that it inserts.